# display data from mongodb to html page using gin-golang?

Tags: mongodb, go, go-gin

I am trying to check if the MongoDB have data with specific username and password. But now I am getting all the data instead of the specified data. Below is my code:

```
r.POST("/login", func(c *gin.Context) {
    logedUser :=[]RegisterdUser{}
    name := c.PostForm("userName")
    Password := c.PostForm("userPassword")

    fmt.Println("inside checking  sectionnnn",name,Password)
    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost:27017")
     if err != nil {
            panic(err)
     }
     s := session.Clone()
     db := s.DB("testing").C("testData")
    //err = db.Find(nil).All(&logedUser)
    err = db.Find(bson.M{"name": name,"password" :Password}).All(&logedUser)
        //err = db.Find({"Name": name},{"Password" :Password}).All(&logedUser)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    log.Println("inside error")
        }
    //if logedUser !=nil{
    //fmt.Println("logged")
    //c.Redirect(301, "/loggedPage")

    //}else{
        //c.Redirect(301, "/loginError")
    //}
    fmt.Println("data fetched",logedUser)

        c.Next()
    defer session.Close()




  })
```

My DB structure is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a7ac6150e04b2e9c18c15af"), "name" : "aswathy", "password" : "aswathyashok" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a7ad3ef0e04b2e9c18c15d1"), "name" : "anupama", "password" : "anu" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a7bf0dcd90e2ccd0bd9785b"), "name" : "reema", "password" : "reemaaa" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a7bf1f6d90e2ccd0bd97895"), "name" : "sreeda", "password" : "sreeda" }
```

The Result of inside checking section is aswathy aswathyshok.

result of data fetched is

> [{aswathy aswathyashok} {anupama anu} {reema reemaaa} {sreeda sreeda}
>   {deena deena} {farsu farsu} {beena beena} {jeena jeena}]

Comment: What you do mean "all the data"? You're not showing the resulting `logedUser` or what you expect to get.

Comment: all data means every data in that collection.the logedUser result is [{aswathy aswathyashok} {anupama anu} {reema reemaaa} {sreeda sreeda} {deena deena} {farsu farsu} {beena beena} {jeena jeena}]@Marc

Comment: Have you checked the values of `name` and `Password`? Your code also doesn't print anything, so we don't even know if this is what you're using. Please edit it with the actual code used and the output values for specific print statements.

Comment: yes i updated my original code .i only want to get the corresponding user data not the all data in logedUser@Marc

Comment: Can you print `name` and `Password` as well just to check you are getting correct data when making the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you are looking for a specific and unique record. If it is so I would suggest to use just a single struct `logedUser := RegisterdUser{}` instead of a slice `logedUser :=[]RegisterdUser{}` and this method https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.One, so you will have `err = db.Find(bson.M{"name": name,"password" :Password}).One(&logedUser)`